# SqlAlchemy: cast to int if possible/test if string is numeric

Tags: python, casting, sqlalchemy, string-matching

I have a TEXT column with a lot of various values, some numeric, some not. I want to find all rows containing a numeric value greater than a given number.

I can use `cast`:

```py
def findAttrValAbove42():
    q = db.query(AttrVal)
    q = q.filter(cast(AttrVal.value, Numeric) > 42)
    return list(q)
```

The problem is when `cast` encounters a row with a value like "cookies", it throws an error. So, I need a way to either have `cast` return a default value on failure, or additionally filter for only numeric values, eg:

```py
def findAttrValAbove42():
    q = db.query(AttrVal)
    q = q.filter(AttrVal.value.isNumeric())
    q = q.filter(cast(AttrVal.value, Numeric) > 42)
    return list(q)
```

But I can't find any "is numeric" or "match regular expression" function that could do that filtering.

Comment: Why do you need to do this? I'm curious about a database design that would require this.

Comment: What DBMS are you using?

Comment: I'm using Postgres, and I've found a way to do regex with it, but I'd prefer a backend-agnostic solution.